# Cassandra data model for ordered range query

Tags: database-design, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm struggling to work out the correct data model for a Cassandra column family/table which will enable me to query what I need.

I only need to store data for a single type of entity, representing a financial transaction. The main fields (applicable for queries, sorting):

1. uuid: unique ID per transaction
2. timestamp: time of transaction
3. source_id: string (low cardinality, typically < 10 unique values across the data set)
4. destination_id: string (low cardinality, typically < 10 unique values across the data set)
5. merchant_id: string (high cardinality, ~100k unique values)

There are additional fields (approx 20 total), but these are not required for query or ordering.

I need to query transactions in the following two ways:

1. By UUID
2. By date range, for exact values of source_id/destination_id, ordered by merchant_id

The UUID query needs to be quick and, whilst the date range query should be as efficient as possible, it is run daily as an offline process so can take longer. It would be good to understand how the query time scales with no. records.

Cassandra will be setup as a cluster of 4 nodes, across 2 data centres, in case this affects the partition key configuration. I'm using Cassandra 2.0.

Being somewhat new to Cassandra, I've been reading about composite keys, timeuuid, slice queries etc but am a little confused. If anyone is able to suggest the right approach, or point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Query 1 is fairly straightforward, in CQL3, this looks like:

```
create table tx_by_uuid (
tx_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
tx_time timestamp,
source_id text,
dest_id text,
merchant_id text
)
```

Query 2 is a bit more complex:
(Note, I'm assuming here that source_id/destination_id refers to requirement that both are specified, and not and either/or situation)

Since we want to query by exact values of the source_id/destination_id we ideally want a primary key that uses a combination of those columns as our partition key. Since those are low cardinality columns, we might run into a problem with lumpy partitioning, but since you have given us some extra information about the number of nodes, we can convince ourselves that source_id+destination_id is an acceptable partition key for this table by observing that if each of those columns has about 10 distinct values, when combined, there will be about 100 distinct values. In a larger cluster, this would not be ideal data distribution and we might want to add a temporal bucket to partition key, but for a four node cluster, we might be alright here.

Since we also want to query by data range, we will want to include the tx_time column as a clustering column. In addition, since we want to see the results ordered by the merchant, that will also need to be a clustering column. Finally, to ensure that the primary key uniquely identifies they individual transactions, the tx_id should be the last clustering column. So the table for query 2 might look like:

```
create table tx_by_merchant(
tx_id uuid,
tx_time timestamp,
source_id text,
dest_id text,
merchant_id text,
primary key((source_id, dest_id), tx_time, merchant_id, tx_id)
)
```

Note that these partitions could be extremely wide, so it might be a good idea to add a year+month supplementary column to the partition key to break those up a bit. Also, if you need to reverse the ordering, have a look at the WITH CLUSTERING ORDER clause.

Queries that retrieve a row uniquely identified by a single primary key are very fast. Queries that fetch from very wide partitions can be somewhat slower, but it will still be faster than trying to accomplish the same thing with a secondary index.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Seeing your suggested primary key to support the range query was helpful for me. I'd previously tried with the timestamp in the partition key and that was giving me an error. As I now understand it, I must constrain the partition key in order to query a range i.e. only query a single node?

Also, if I've understood correctly, your example requires records to be duplicated across two tables? Is there any way to also have efficient access to records by UUID with a single table? I assume a secondary index on UUID isn't a good idea due to high cardinality?

Comment: In Cassandra, duplicating data into different structures for efficient querying is just how we roll ;) And you're exactly correct about the high cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Another question on my requirement to query records in a date range, but order results by merchant ID - the primary key you suggest only orders by merchant_id for records with identical tx_time values. In other words, if I query tx_by_merchant for a date range, I really get records ordered by tx_time. Is my best approach here to query by date and put the results into a temporary table which I can index on merchant_id (with a fixed partition key)?

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Then the question becomes, how many rows do you think you will match overall with this query? If it is a ton, do you really want all that back in one query? I suspect the best option is to create 10 minute (or 1 minute, or 1 hour) buckets of transactions. The bucket then becomes part of the partition key and you can get the merchant ordering that you want. The tradeoff would be that to query over a time range in multiple buckets you would have to issue multiple queries. Let me know which option sounds appealing and I'll edit the answer to show how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for following up. The solution I've implemented is to use an additional table to order by merchant_id (3 tables total). I insert the results from the date range query into this table (using a new UUID partition key for all results) and query this to sort by merchant_id.